# proof check : showing convex function has increasing slope

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Show that for any $x,y\in X,0<\mu<\lambda$, we have 
$$\frac{f(x+\mu y)-f(x)}{\mu}\le\frac{f(x+\lambda y)-f(x)}{\lambda} $$

My proof first shows that $x = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\mu}(x+\mu y)-\frac{\mu}{\lambda-\mu}(x+\lambda y)$. Then, \begin{align*}f(x) &= f\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\mu}(x+\mu y)-\frac{\mu}{\lambda-\mu}(x+\lambda y)\right)\\
& \le \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\mu}f\left((x+\mu y)\right)-\frac{\mu}{\lambda-\mu} f\left((x+\lambda y)\right)\\
(\lambda-\mu)f(x) &\le \lambda f\left((x+\mu y)\right)-\mu f\left((x+\lambda y)\right)\\
\mu(f\left((x+\lambda y)\right)-f(x)) &\le \lambda(f\left((x+\mu y)\right)-f(x))\\
\frac{f(x+\lambda y)-f(x)}{\lambda}&\le\frac{f(x+\mu y)-f(x)}{\mu}\end{align*}

Which I get different from what question asks. At which point I made a mistake?? Thanks,

Comment: You can't apply the convex inequality with the negative $-\mu/(\lambda - \mu)$. Otherwise said, your point $x$ is *not* between the other two. But you've got the right idea.

Comment: @dxiv But here $-\mu/(\lambda-\mu)=1-\lambda/(\lambda-\mu)$

Comment: Right, but it's not enough that the two add to $1$. The convex inequality requires that both be within $[0,1]$, while your $\lambda/(\lambda - \mu) \gt 1$ and $-\mu/(\lambda - \mu) \lt 0$.

Comment: @dxiv Got that! thanks !!